# using a button in recycler view to open up maps

Tags: android

I am trying to set an intents for a button that appears on a card in a recycler view, however I get an error with the startActivity(intent) part saying "Cannot resolve method 'startActivity(android.Content.intent)'" I am new to this and I am not sure where I am going wrong as the code works in other parts of my app.

Here is my adapter showing my code:

```
public class EventCalenderAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<EventCalenderAdapter.ViewHolder> {


String[] title;
String[] time_start;
String[] time_finish;
String[] date;
String[] description;
String[] loc_lat;
String[] loc_long;

static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    CardView cardView;
    TextView titleView;
    TextView auxView1;
    TextView auxView2;
    TextView auxView3;
    Button time_date;
    Button location;

    public ViewHolder(CardView card) {
        super(card);
        cardView = card;
        titleView = (TextView) card.findViewById(R.id.text1);
        auxView1 = (TextView) card.findViewById(R.id.text2);
        auxView2 = (TextView) card.findViewById(R.id.text3);
        auxView3 = (TextView) card.findViewById(R.id.text4);
        time_date = (Button) card.findViewById(R.id.time_date);
        location = (Button) card.findViewById(R.id.location);
    }
}

public EventCalenderAdapter (Context context) {

    title = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.title);
    time_start = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.time_start);
    time_finish = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.time_finish);
    date = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.date);
    description = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.description);
    loc_lat = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.loc_lat);
    loc_long = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.loc_long);

}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int i) {
    CardView v = (CardView) LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.event_task, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, final int i) {
    viewHolder.titleView.setText(title[i]);
    viewHolder.auxView1.setText("Date: "+ date[i]);
    viewHolder.auxView2.setText("Time: " + time_start[i] + " - " + time_finish[i]);
    viewHolder.auxView3.setText("Details: " + description[i]);

    viewHolder.time_date.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });

    viewHolder.location.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String uri = String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "geo:%f,%f", loc_lat[i], loc_long[i]);
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

}
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return title.length;
}


}
```

Comment: try my answer ,i can't try it i just know that you need to pass `context` to your adapter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to use `context` to call the `startActivity()`

```
ViewHolder vh=new ViewHolder(card,MainActivity.this);//use it like this
```

here is ViewHolder Class

```
static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    CardView cardView;
    TextView titleView;
    TextView auxView1;
    TextView auxView2;
    TextView auxView3;
    Button time_date;
    Button location;
    Context context;

    public ViewHolder(CardView card,Context context) {
        super(card);
        cardView = card;
        titleView = (TextView) card.findViewById(R.id.text1);
        auxView1 = (TextView) card.findViewById(R.id.text2);
        auxView2 = (TextView) card.findViewById(R.id.text3);
        auxView3 = (TextView) card.findViewById(R.id.text4);
        time_date = (Button) card.findViewById(R.id.time_date);
        location = (Button) card.findViewById(R.id.location);
        this.context=context;
    }
}

public EventCalenderAdapter (Context context) {

    title = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.title);
    time_start = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.time_start);
    time_finish = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.time_finish);
    date = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.date);
    description = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.description);
    loc_lat = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.loc_lat);
    loc_long = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.loc_long);

}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int i) {
    CardView v = (CardView) LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.event_task, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, final int i) {
    viewHolder.titleView.setText(title[i]);
    viewHolder.auxView1.setText("Date: "+ date[i]);
    viewHolder.auxView2.setText("Time: " + time_start[i] + " - " + time_finish[i]);
    viewHolder.auxView3.setText("Details: " + description[i]);

    viewHolder.time_date.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });

    viewHolder.location.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String uri = String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "geo:%f,%f", loc_lat[i], loc_long[i]);
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

}
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return title.length;
}


}
```

Comment: now it is saying cannot resolve symbol context, do I need to declare context somewhere?

Comment: did you add `Context context` ?

Comment: I added it all I even put it above the static class where the string arrays are declared, the app runs but then forces stop

Comment: Where do I put the ViewHolder vh part of the code, I have put all the other parts in and now I get an error in the onCreateViewHolder saying that view holder(v) cannot be applied

Comment: And it it still can't resolve the symbol in the intent

Comment: yes the new holder(v) can't be applied change it with new holder(v,yourActivity.this);

Comment: the viewholder still can't be applied

Comment: does it really helps ? i mean you accepted the answer and the comment said that your vieolder still can't be applied ?

Comment: It got me there in the end, I noticed "geo:%f%f" wasn't working, so I adapted it slightly and it worked, I put the the coordinates next the geo directly, but without your answer I wouldn't have been able to do it.